# How do I select GCC version in nix-shell?

Tags: nixos

I am requesting GCC 8, but I get GCC 7 instead.

```
$ nix-shell -p gcc8
[nix-shell:~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.0
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to base your environment on `stdenvNoCC`, instead of `stdenv`

That means, you may create a `shell.nix` or `default.nix` file in your current directory, defining the environment, and then run `nix-shell`.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
  qpidEnv = stdenvNoCC.mkDerivation {
    name = "my-gcc8-environment";
    buildInputs = [
        gcc8
        go
        ruby_2_4
        gdb
        swig
        # libev
        #...
    ];
  };
}
```

Now, it works as expected

```
$ nix-shell
[nix-shell:~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.1.0
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nix-devel/of6P-sEtQN0

Comment: I think you can also mention the wiki's say on this issue: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/C#Use_a_different_compiler_version

Comment: What about if in addition, I also want to have a `cmake` version 2.8.8? And by the way, from the looks of `gcc8` or `ruby_2_4` it seems that the version has no standard way of format and it is hard-to-get. Is there an index listing of these various versions?

Comment: Probably best to raise separate questions. The only thing I can answer is how to figure what's available. I usually look into pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix in nixpkgs repository, https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/aab7e12a872e46c466ab3cb9c93dd1974dcd6eb9/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L8986

Comment: Btw, does dropping `cmake_2_8` into the package list work? The various ruby etc. packages in the answer are not needed for gcc to work, it is just what environment I needed besides gcc8 at that moments

Comment: I added `cmake_2_8` into the list and it gave me `cmake version 2.8.12.2`. Thanks. I also observed, it gave me `gcc 8.2.0`. Whereas, you got `gcc 8.1.0`. The understanding that I picked here is that `gcc8` in the `buildInputs` list is binary-compiled and stored somewhere and then they bumped it to newer gcc version as they see fit. This made me ask, aside from this one binary cache, are there others?

Comment: It was 8.1.0 at the point of writing. Now it apparently is 8.2.0. What you can do is to checkout nixpkgs repository at commit which has versions you are interested in, and use a switch to use that local copy (don't remember what it is now). Nix purposely drops older versions of packages and there is policy to limit the number of versions provided concurrently.

Comment: In the `nix run -f channel:nixos-19.03 gcc8` command, you can afaik specify the version of the channel somehow. I recall that bazel rules for haskell based on nix used a specific fixed version of nixpkgs, for reproducibility.

Comment: To usel local checkout of nixpkgs, eiter cli switch `-Inixpkgs=/home/jdanek/nix/nixpkgs` or `-f /home/jdanek/nix/nixpkgs` or maybe `export NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=/home/jdanek/nix/nixpkgs` should work.

Comment: I would like to point out that although this solves the problem, this does not explain why the path to the newly installed gcc did not have a higher priority than that of the existing one. This feels counter intuitive so I presume there is a good reason for this, but it would be nice to hear that reason in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use `nix run` instead. It behaves better, and also has nicer progress indicator when downloading packages.

```
jdanek@nixos ~ % nix run -f channel:nixos-19.03 gcc8
[jdanek@nixos:~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.3.0
```